# How to convert the Android.bp file to gradle script file?

Tags: android, android-source

I have a AOSP android app code which contains Andriod.bp file. Now I want to run this app in Android stdio. So, for that I need to convert this .bp file to Gradle script file. How to convert the Android.bp file to gradle script file?